# Best/Quickest way to override a Form Class method for all forms in namespace

Tags: c#, forms, escaping, key, overriding

My end goal is that I want every form in my project to handle the escape key.

I could just override the ProcessCmdKey method in every single form in my project but that's very time consuming and in my eyes, a little bit untidy.

Is there a way to apply this change to every class that inherits the Form Class?

Comment: Why not just create base form class for all your forms, override ProcessCmdKey there (once) and then inherit all your forms from it?

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So moving answer from comment here: just create base class for all your forms, override ProcessCmdKey there (once) and inherit all your forms from that base class.

To create a base class, create a new blank form and then add your override to that class.

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in all your forms instead of inheriting from the Form class you inherit from your new base class.

```
public partial class AssetForm : BaseForm
{
    public AssetForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```